# Percents rounding for element width in CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's suppose I have three `div`s with width `33.3%` in a container:

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

div.inner {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner" style="background-color:red;"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div class="inner" style="background-color:black;"></div>
</div>
```

Can I state that in modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera), with any user zoom, total width of the three inner `div`s will be <= container width? In other words, can there be a situation where because of rounding their total width exceeds the container width?

Comment: You should use flexbox for a problem like this. Setting flex: 1 on each element would make them all equal width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do to help with this is use two decimal places -- ie `33.33%` rather than `33.3%`. This will reduce the margin of error for any rounding problems.

Once you're at that level of precision, rounding is unlikely to be an issue, but if you do still have a problem with it, or you just want to be precise, you can always do something like this:

```
div.inner {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}
div.inner:last-child {
  width: 33.34%;
}
```

...to override the last element so it adds up to 100%.

Overall though, the best bet is probably to stop using floats; unless you need to support ancient IE versions, there are much better options now for building this kind of layout.

Comment: If you really think that 33.33% will be handled any differently from 33.3% or even 33%, then you probably are thinking mathematically and not how the browsers will actually calculate it. How will 33.33% of 100 pixel reduce the margin of error vs. using 33.3%? In both cases you end up with a fractional pixel, and who cares what the fraction value is? What's important is what the browser will do with it afterwards, round it up, down, or to the nearest integer. See my answer and the link at the bottom.

Comment: @RacilHilan - The browsers do operate at a sub-pixel level, and viewport widths are often hundreds of pixels wide, so fractions of a percent are relevant. [See the table here](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/) for what kind of decimal precision each browser considers (hint, even IE7 looks at two decimals).

Comment: That's the link from my answer returned back to me :). Are you talking about the percentage accuracy? That's a mathematical concept and the browsers like any software can use any accuracy they want. I didn't have any objection to that and that was not the point. The point is that after the calculation, the boxes need to be rendered on the screen using physics not math :P. How do you expect the screen to display 0.33 pixel? :) So it doesn't really matter if width is 33.30 or 33.33, they will be displayed using 33 pixel ;). That's why the browser will round the sub-pixel in final step.

Comment: Here is a [little experiment](https://jsfiddle.net/8ze0rosy/) that you can easily do to see what I mean. Create a `div` with `width: 100px` and place three `div`s inside it giving them the width of 33%, 33.3%, and 33.33%. You will see that they all have the exact same width probably on any browser you use. So like I said, your 33.33% doesn't make a difference here. In some cases it may cause some browsers to round up instead of down if the difference is above .5 vs below .5, but that's just  difference, not more accuracy ;).

Comment: Well, if you're constraining width to 100px then you're right; you don't need much precision in your percentages. But most screens are a lot wider than that. The OP also asked to support any zoom level, which again increases the need for precision. Finally, yes, you **can** render a third of a pixel. That's what [sub-pixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) is all about. It mostly applies to fonts, and it doesn't magically make your screen get extra pixels, but it is a thing, and browsers do calculate widths and positions to a higher precision than individual pixels.

Comment: LOL, yes you can render a third pixel using sub-pixel rendering, but only if your color is Red, Green, or Blue. Other colors will have to go with a different percentage of the pixel :). You cannot render any fraction you want. In all cases, there is still no difference between 0.3 and 0.33 pixel :P. Yes, if the container is wider than 1000px, there will be a difference, but that's not the question. The question was whether the 3 boxes can go over 100%. In fact the 33.33% + 33.34% increases that chance compared to 33.3%, because you are at 100% instead of 99.9% :)

Comment: I'm going to quit here because we're clearly both of us missing what the other is trying to say, and it really isn't worth getting into an argument about.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically you are correct, if that is ever visible to the naked eye, I strongly doubt it, and I will say that in most cases the rounding difference will get lost. However if you want to be sure that the browser does take care and really fills in the whole div, you could use flexbox instead:

```
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display:flex;
}

div.inner {
 flex-grow:1;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background-color:black;"></div>
</div>
```

I personally much prefer flexbox over float div with percentage width, it makes adding/removing divs much easier but that is a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers round fractional pixels down, but not all. And here, by browser I also mean each version of each browser, as different versions of any browser may handle fractional pixels differently. So theoretically, your three `33.3%` boxes may overflow their parent container in some version of some browser.

Think about it, the browser has to meet constraints that can’t all be satisfied at the same time. Your example of three 33.3% will mathematically be 99.9%, so let's change it to four 25% to be exactly 100% just for the sake of example:

1. The 4 boxes of width 25% should occupy the same number of pixels.
2. The 4 boxes should end exactly at the edge of the container. There should not be an extra pixel (and they should not be wrapped due to that).
3. The 4 boxes should always touch each other visually. There should not be a gap or overlap.

It's really hard to meet all those constraints at the same time, so different browsers (and different versions of each browser) try to satisfy those constraints with different priority. That means if you render the exact same page in different browsers it may look slightly different. The different will be very hard to notice because it is only a pixel or two, but if you compare them and look closely, you will see it.

Here is a nice article/experiment: [Browser Rounding and Fractional Pixels](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/).